# evidence for wavenature of particles from deBroglie wavelength

Tags: electrons, diffraction

Doing a search on electron diffraction this, for example http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/davger2.html , the evidence does not look overwhelming for the significance of the deBroglie wavelength.

Do electron diffraction or other experiments give results that can be predicted using the precise value of the deBroglie wavelength ?

Davvison and Germer showed there is what looks like an interference pattern.But could this be just because of a pattern produced by the crystal lattice ?

Comment: Atomic physics offers plenty of highly precise evidence for the validity of quantum mechanics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of background research.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to perform the
[Double-Slit Experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment)
using electrons.  The resulting diffraction pattern matches that predicted by quantum mechanics, with characteristics defined by the deBroglie wavelength of the electrons.  When I was in college, I watched a Professor perform this experiment in class.

No other theory ever devised, aside from QM, explains this diffraction pattern.

Comment: How did they show the pattern in your college experiment? I have never seen it in person.

Comment: He had a detector that only detected electrons scattered in a narrow angle.  He rotated it through different angles and had the class count out ticks per minute.  He wrote the numbers on the chalkboard, and the pattern emerged.

Comment: All of this in a vacuum? It sounds like a scattering experiment, but not like an electron double slit. See e.g. http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01342460 for an experiment of that kind.

Comment: My question is not about QM. It is about the deBroglie wavelength only.

Comment: @CuriousOne It was definitely a double-slit experiment.  Electrons were fired from a source, down a tube at a pair of slits.  Beyond that was a movable arm at the end of which was a detector.  The arm could rotate around an axis that coincided with the slits.  Entire apparatus was evacuated.

Comment: @user1894243:  The deBroglie wavelength is one of the parameters used (along with the distance between the slits) to calculate the diffraction pattern.  Hence its significance in this experiment.

Comment: I think what you saw was probably a diffraction experiment on a crystal. An electron double slit on a macroscopic slit has only minute deflections.

Comment: @user3294068  if think your electron double slit experiment answers my question, if the calculated deBroglie wavelength matches/predicts the maxima/minima, which it probably does. But I cannot find an online description with these details.The wikipedia link you gave does not give such detail.

Comment: This  wikipedia article answers my question https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davisson%E2%80%93Germer_experiment#A_breakthrough